# Safari always loads a different region for a specific website

Tags: macos, safari, browser-history

On my Mac, If I type in godaddy.com or [www.godaddy.com](http://www.godaddy.com) to the Safari browser, or if I search for godaddy and click the link for https://www.godaddy.com - the browser always loads tw.godaddy.com in Taiwanese

I've opened Safari's "Show All History" and searched for any tw.godaddy.com sites in the past to delete them. There are no cases of this domain in the history now.

Any ideas on what is causing this redirect and how I could stop it?

macOS 12.4 Safari Version 15.5 (17613.2.7.1.8)

In a private browser, this redirect doesn't happen.

Comment: Could you edit this so we know what OS, version of safari you use? On iPad, the redirect doesn’t happen just now on iPadOS 15.5

Comment: Thanks @bmike - I've added this to the question. I'm sure this is not some widespread issue and more specific to my machine and browser, but I can't tell what causes this. In a private browser the redirect doesn't happen

Comment: Nice details, maybe someone can help enable console mode to capture the redirect / cookies that interact between when you enter the text to the server sends results.

Comment: If it doesn't happen in a private browser, this sounds like a cookie/localstorage issue, or some kind of extension.  Any browser extensions in use?  What if you cleared stored data via Preferences -> Privacy -> Manage Website Data -> search for godaddy domains and delete all?

Comment: @vykor seems like that fixed it! Thanks for pointing me in the "Manage Website Data" direction. If you want to post it as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally if a website misbehaves in some way, but doesn't do that if you use Private Browsing / Incognito (and you don't use a browser extension that might affect that site), it's likely caused by a corrupted cookie or bad data left in the website's LocalStorage.  This can be fixed by clearing that local data.

In desktop Safari, close any tabs that belong to that website.  Then, go to `Preferences -> Privacy -> Manage Website Data`, search for the website, and remove local data. Then open the site again and see if that fixes things.

Answer (score 0):

Is this probably a problem of your country code? Are you living by any chance in Taiwan?

Living in Germany, entering http://www.godaddy.com I am redirected to https://www.godaddy.com/de-de in German language, although my preferred system language is English.

greetings

marek